# Two classes to extends one activity?

Tags: java, android

Pretty new in Java and Android.

My situation:
I have an app where users are looking some images.
Also have and an admob at the bottom.

what I need is if the user click on the admob and returns back to the app to hide the admob.view (onDismissScreen).

At the moment I have

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
```

Which is listening for clicks on the images.
As I see I need also :

```
public class BannerSample extends Activity implements AdListener {
```

To be able to use onDismissScreen.

How can I combine these together.
Or some other solution if available?

Pretty new in android and don`t have practice so please for some example :)

Thanks all!

Comment: Can't you have a single class implement both interfaces ! I don't know about Android though !!!

Comment: yes, In ANdroid also you can have a single Class implementing the two interfaces

Comment: please strengthen your basic in Java before going into android. Rushing things is not good at all.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the following:

```
public class BannerSample extends Activity implements AdListener, OnClickListener {
```

And implement the necessary methods in the BannerSample.

When implementing interfaces, you can implement multiple interfaces by separating them with a comma. Note, however, that you can only extend from one class.

Comment: Yeah just did it.
But I don`t see them working.
I`m log.d and Toast but it never enters there.